# unable to start sdk manager in eclipse

Tags: android, sdk

I've installed Eclipse (ADT bundle) recently. To complete a task I tried to launch sdk manager, but that is not working.

The following is the error that is shown in console.

> [2013-09-29 23:53:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   /home/dinesh/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130911/sdk/tools/android: 1:
>   /home/dinesh/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130911/sdk/tools/android: java:
>   not found [2013-09-29 23:53:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   /home/dinesh/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130911/sdk/tools/android: 1:
>   /home/dinesh/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130911/sdk/tools/android: java:
>   not found [2013-09-29 23:53:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]
>   /home/dinesh/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130911/sdk/tools/android: 110:
>   exec: java: not found

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you have not installed your Java JDK. Android needs the Java JDK to compile the Java files and Java code. Please see the following reference for downloading the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). If not, then are you sure that the SDK location is correct? Please check it through the following step in Eclipse/ADT:

> Windows -> Preferences -> SDK Location

.

Answer (score 0):

goto Windows-->preferences-->android set the correct path of your sdk.
Then restart your Eclipse